# How to add wsdl file to java project resources correctly and get it path

Tags: java, wsdl, resources, urlconnection

i have wsdl file and i need to add this file to my java project resources. I have generated code from wsdl by wsimport.
What i have - 
1) added file to resources package
2) in my class from wsipmort i change url property from

```
URL url = null;
url = new URL("http://someUrl/someWsdlFile?wsdl");
```

to

```
File file = new File("resources/someWsdlFile.wsdl");
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
        url = new URL(absolutePath);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        e = new WebServiceException(ex);
    }
```

and when i run my code i get an exception -

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
```

when i have url like this

```
url = new URL("file:C:/Users/someWsdlFile.wsdl");
```

my code works correctly without exception

```
unknown protocol: d
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `File.toString` would return `/some/path/to/file.wsdl`, **not** a URI. [`File.toURI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI()), on the other hand, would return an URI. In either case this won't work in production as the file would be located _inside_ the Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a resource from the search path used to load classes, use following method.

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("someWsdlFile.wsdl");
```

If load your resource available in the classpath then use folloing method.

```
 yourClass.class.getResource("someWsdlFile.wsdl");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Boris and ravthiru its work now.
i do this

```
String absolutePath = null;
        try {
            absolutePath = String.valueOf(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("someWsdlFile.wsdl").toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(absolutePath);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Why get the `URI`, convert it to a `String` and then convert it back to a `URL`? Are you trying to generate extra heat from the computer? Maybe [`URI.toURL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#toURL()) would be a better choice? Unless of course you wish to test your computer's cooling system...

Comment: @BoristheSpider ohh, i understand what u mean (( its my fault. Now its -
         url = new URL(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("someWsdlFile.wsdl").toString());